# Ubuntu Studio 22.04 Auto-login in-active and using On-screen Login

Tags: keyboard, kde, login-screen, ubuntu-studio

This is with a fresh install of Ubuntu Studio 22.04, the earlier /home/user folder contents intact to preserve extensive wine DAW plugins and with a dual boot into Windows 10.

Ubuntu Studio 22.04 uses KDE Plasma, but the System Settings are very different from Kubuntu.

I have checked all the System Settings to confirm that no touch-screens are detected, there is no way to enable an on-screen keyboard and that my user is set for auto-login.

On booting, an on-screen keyboard appears, which can be mouse operated. On closing the keyboard, a normal mouse/keyboard log-in screen appears even though auto-login is set for my user id in System Settings.  Login occurs correctly, once the user password is entered.

It is a minor inconvenience, but I would like to sort it out.

Comment: It should be under your accessibility settings or "ease of access". Sometimes these settings are available from the login screen too. But also, check out [this answer](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?t=143311#article393402) and if it works I'll add it as a solution. I have no way of testing it at the moment.

Comment: I have checked the Accessibility settings and the Startup Settings, again, but with no luck. Auto-login is still enabled for my account. However, the addition of the /etc/sddm.conf file with the entries suggested has successfully got rid of the virtual keyboard. There is just the auto-login to sort out. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, so you may be able to set autologin through the same `/etc/sddm.conf` file. See [this tutorial](https://linuxconfig.org/linux-kde4-user-auto-login-command-line-version). Scroll down to where it says "Enable auto login from command line".

Answer (score 1):

mchid Found the answer

Create /etc/sddm.conf with the contents:

```
[General]
InputMethod=

[Autologin]
User=<USER ID>
Session=plasma.desktop
```

The lines,

```
[General] 
InputMethod=
```

stop the on-screen keyboard, and

```
[Autologin] 
User=<USER ID> 
Session=plasma.desktop
```

provides auto-login. It appears that the KDE Plasma System Settings for auto-login do not generate the necessary file entry.

Comment: Works, but then prompts for the password anyway after login, for kdewallet. I was able to go to `KWalletManager`, and it let me set the password to blank.